# Mock FileInputStream using Mockito/PowerMockito without having an existing file

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am writing a `JUnit` for a method that uses `FileInputStream` and in the `constructor` only the file name is passed. The file is created as part of a servlet request and this file is not stored any where.

I am trying to `Mock` `FileInputStream` using `PowerMockito` so that it gives me a mocked file object. Unfortunately I get `FileNotFoundException` which is valid but I am not sure how to test this method then because the file doesn't exist.

Method under test:

```
public String viewReport() throws Exception {
    this.inputStream = new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);

    try {
        boolean returnReport = validateRequest();
        if (returnReport) {
            intgList = this.generateViewIntegrationReportData(getESignUIConfig());
            this.createCSVFile(intgList, new FileWriter(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE));
        } else {
            failureResponse(msgs, 400);
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        msgs.add(new Message(ESignatureIntegrationMessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR, 
                    UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_CODE_500, UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_TEXT_SERVICE_ERROR));
        failureResponse(msgs, 500);
        return null;
    }

    return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.REPORT_REPSONSE;
}
```

JUnit test so far.

```
@Test
public void testViewReport() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> actionMap = new HashMap<>();
    actionMap.put("application", "ESignatureIntegrationAction");

    ActionContext.setContext(new ActionContext(actionMap));

    FileInputStream inputStream = Mockito.mock(FileInputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(inputStream);

    action = new ESignatureIntegrationAction();
    action.viewReport();
}
```

I get an `exception` when the code reaches to `new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE);`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The usual caveat: if you would be using a factory (together with dependency injection) ... then you would not need Powermock to mock a call to new.

Comment: You mean I should inject FileInputStream using Spring?

Comment: What would your test actually test, if there's no file from which your code can read something?

Comment: So this method is a Struts2 action which downloads this file as a CSV file. I  know that I cannot test the content of a CSV and this is the reason I am trying to mock the file creation part.

Comment: And you also may want to learn about the principles of [Dependency Inversion](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:dependency_inversion_principle) (you don't need a framework for DI) and [Single Level of Abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction).

Comment: Your code uses the same file name (`DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE`) for Input and Output?

Comment: You need to separate the code which reads or writes to files (or at least creates the input and outputstreams) from the one which does the logic you want to test. Then you can test the latter one with "mocked" `InputStream` and `OutputStream` instances.

Comment: Why does your code handle some exceptions (`catch (Exception e)`) but does still (declare) `throws Exception` if opening of the input file does not work (`new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE)`)?

Comment: Every single line of this "code" screams of wrong design. There is no point of unit testing this function as a function like this has no right to exist.

Comment: This is what people say when they don't know how to trouble shoot.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to refactor your code in a way that allows testing without a mocking framework.

It could look somewhat like this:

```
public class YourClass {

    // ...

    public String viewReport()  {
        try {
            boolean isValidRequest = validateRequest();
            if (isValidRequest) {
                IntegrationReportCsvFileHandler fileHandler = new IntegrationReportCsvFileHandler();
                IntegrationReportData inputData = fileHandler.readData(new FileInputStream(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE));

                IntegrationReportGenerator generator = new IntegrationReportGenerator();
                IntegrationReportData outputData = generator.processData(inputData, getESignUIConfig());

                fileHandler.writeReport(outputData, new FileWriter(DOCUSIGN_REPORT_FILE));
            } else {
                failureResponse(msgs, 400);
                return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.FAILURE_RESPONSE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            msgs.add(new Message(ESignatureIntegrationMessageTypeEnum.MESSAGE_TYPE_ERROR, 
                        UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_CODE_500, UiIntegrationKeyConstants.UI_INTEGRATION_ERROR_TEXT_SERVICE_ERROR));
            failureResponse(msgs, 500);
            return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.FAILURE_RESPONSE;
        }

        return UiIntegrationKeyConstants.REPORT_RESPONSE;
    } 

    // ...

}

public class IntegrationReportData {
    // your custom data structure
    // may as well just be a List<Data>
    // may be different for input and output
}

public class IntegrationReportException extends Exception {
    // your custom exception
    public IntegrationReportException(String message) { super(exception); }
}

public class IntegrationReportGenerator {

    public IntegrationReportData processData(IntegrationReportData data, ESignConfig config) throws IntegrationReportException {
        // here's your logic that requires testing
    }

}

public class IntegrationReportCsvFileHandler {

    public IntegrationReportData readData(InputStream input) throws IOException  {
        // read data from given input stream
    }

    public void writeData(IntegrationReportData data, OutputStreamWriter outputWriter) throws IOException {
        // write data to given output stream
    }

}
```

That way the `IntegrationReportGenerator` would be easily testable.